# How to make a custom view for the following layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have several tiles in my `home_activity.xml` and I want to make a custom view for the tile so that I don't have to code every attribute for every tile independently.

Here is the code snippet for adding the components in every tile in the home activity which I want to make a custom view for. I have included examples of two such tiles.

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/home_card_elev"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/contact_tracer_tile"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonback2"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/home_card_elev"
                        app:layout_column="0"
                        app:layout_row="1">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/image_button3"
                            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ImageButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imgbut_text3"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:contentDescription="Card Image"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgbut_text3"
                            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_symptom_tracker" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/imgbut_text3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/mukta_semibold"
                            android:text="@string/social_distancing_tile"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/blackcolor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/home_card_font"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/home_card_elev"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_column="1"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/onair_tile"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonback2"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/home_card_elev"
                        app:layout_column="1"
                        app:layout_row="0">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/image_button4"
                            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ImageButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imgbut_text4"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:contentDescription="Card Image"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgbut_text4"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_onair" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/imgbut_text4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/mukta_semibold"
                            android:text="@string/onair_tile"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/blackcolor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/home_card_font"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use include tag in home_activity.xml file (or where you need include).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/included_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/include_tiles_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

p.s] make mutiple includes.

for example, in home_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="100dp"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_layout"     <!-- 아이디 설정 가능 -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_timeset"      <!-- xml을 적는데 주의점 android빼고 -->
        />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_timeset"
        />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/custom_timeset"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in java file,

```
View include01 = findViewById(R.id.include_layout);
View include02 = findViewById(R.id.include_layout2);
View include03 = findViewById(R.id.include_layout3);

TextView tv1 = (TextView) include01.findViewById(R.id.txt_startTime);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) include01.findViewById(R.id.txt_endTime);
TextView tv3 = (TextView) include02.findViewById(R.id.txt_startTime);
TextView tv4 = (TextView) include02.findViewById(R.id.txt_endTime);
TextView tv5 = (TextView) include03.findViewById(R.id.txt_startTime);
TextView tv6 = (TextView) include03.findViewById(R.id.txt_endTime);
```

this make sepearate views.

Comment: I wanted the code to put in a new `layout` folder which I can use in the `home_activity` so that I don't have to keep giving attributes every time in the home layout.

Comment: did you want to make one layout and re-use that? if you use include or merge tag, it make easy. and you don't need to add attributes in every layout.

Comment: will i also be able to add unique IDs to the views with those tags?

Comment: yes sure, you can make multiple include tags and use seperatly. I added in my answer